# Get translated monthNames/dayNames as array in Yii

Tags: php, internationalization, yii, fullcalendar, translation

Yii have a lot of translations in framework/i18n/data/%lang%.php files.
Here are for example the [german translations](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/i18n/data/de_de.php)

I want to use [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my Yii project.
To translate this Calendar, i must provide an array of monthNames/dayNames for current language.
[Fullcalendar monthNames Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNames/)

What is the best way in Yii to generate array like this:

```
['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: you want same output as that JavaScript array?

Comment: I want to get PHP array of monthNames for current language. I can us use json_encode() later, to convert it to JS for Fullcalendar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate that with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) (or Yii native `CJSON::encode()`) and the data provided by Yii:

```
json_encode(
    include('path/to/yii/framework/i18n/data/de_de.php')['monthNames']['wide']
);
```

(This syntax required PHP 5.4 for [array dereferencing](http://php.net/array#example-88))

From the current locale inside Yii that is:

```
json_encode(
    Yii::app()->locale->getMonthNames()
)
```

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLocale#getMonthNames-detail

Comment: This solution would work, but it is not the Yii way to do it. It can stop working if framework move this files, or update array keys...

Comment: Any idea how i can get it with CDateFormatter or other formating classes?

Comment: You could do it with `CDateFormatter::formatMonth()`. Or you get the month name directly from the locale with `CLocale::getMonthName(1 - 12, 'wide')`

Comment: `CLocale::getMonthNames()` is the way, i looking for, but i get CException `Property "DefaultController._data" is not defined.`

Comment: @TUNER88: I added that to the answer and also placed a link into the docs. Didn't know you can get the whole array out of it at once. This looks exactly what you're looking for then I guess. Happy coding!